# python -all combinations of the given length of a array

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

If I have:

```
a=[[1,2,3],['a','b'],[7,8,9],['c','d','e']]
```

I know I should use:

```
for t in itertools.product(*a):
    print t
```

to get all combinations such as

```
[(1,'a',7,'c'),(1,'a',7,'d')....]
```

However, if I want to set a length subsequence of elements, what should I do?
For example, the result I want is (if I set 3 as a length):

```
[(1,'a',7),(1,'a','c')....]
```

which are all combinations with length 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using an outer loop to get all the combinations of 3 sublists in `a`, and then an inner loop to generate the Cartesian products of those sublists:

```
import itertools

a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], [7, 8, 9], ['c', 'd', 'e']]

for groups in itertools.combinations(a, 3):
    for t in itertools.product(*groups):
        print(t)
```

**output**

```
(1, 'a', 7)
(1, 'a', 8)
(1, 'a', 9)
(1, 'b', 7)
(1, 'b', 8)
(1, 'b', 9)
(2, 'a', 7)
(2, 'a', 8)
(2, 'a', 9)
(2, 'b', 7)
(2, 'b', 8)
(2, 'b', 9)
(3, 'a', 7)
(3, 'a', 8)
(3, 'a', 9)
(3, 'b', 7)
(3, 'b', 8)
(3, 'b', 9)
(1, 'a', 'c')
(1, 'a', 'd')
(1, 'a', 'e')
(1, 'b', 'c')
(1, 'b', 'd')
(1, 'b', 'e')
(2, 'a', 'c')
(2, 'a', 'd')
(2, 'a', 'e')
(2, 'b', 'c')
(2, 'b', 'd')
(2, 'b', 'e')
(3, 'a', 'c')
(3, 'a', 'd')
(3, 'a', 'e')
(3, 'b', 'c')
(3, 'b', 'd')
(3, 'b', 'e')
(1, 7, 'c')
(1, 7, 'd')
(1, 7, 'e')
(1, 8, 'c')
(1, 8, 'd')
(1, 8, 'e')
(1, 9, 'c')
(1, 9, 'd')
(1, 9, 'e')
(2, 7, 'c')
(2, 7, 'd')
(2, 7, 'e')
(2, 8, 'c')
(2, 8, 'd')
(2, 8, 'e')
(2, 9, 'c')
(2, 9, 'd')
(2, 9, 'e')
(3, 7, 'c')
(3, 7, 'd')
(3, 7, 'e')
(3, 8, 'c')
(3, 8, 'd')
(3, 8, 'e')
(3, 9, 'c')
(3, 9, 'd')
(3, 9, 'e')
('a', 7, 'c')
('a', 7, 'd')
('a', 7, 'e')
('a', 8, 'c')
('a', 8, 'd')
('a', 8, 'e')
('a', 9, 'c')
('a', 9, 'd')
('a', 9, 'e')
('b', 7, 'c')
('b', 7, 'd')
('b', 7, 'e')
('b', 8, 'c')
('b', 8, 'd')
('b', 8, 'e')
('b', 9, 'c')
('b', 9, 'd')
('b', 9, 'e')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for t in itertools.product(*a):
```

With

```
for t in itertools.product(*a, repeat=3):
```

And take a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for further details

Comment: It gives me 3 repeated full length of a combination such as:
    
    [(1, 'a', 7, 'c', 1, 'a', 7, 'c', 1, 'a', 7, 'c'), ....]

Comment: it isn't doing what is mentioned in the question